# Google maps API strokePosition simply doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been using the google maps API for years and I have never seen the strokePosition styling option work for shapes. Here is an example of my code, which will draw perfectly if strokePosition is not included:

```
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 50,
  strokeColor: '#00FF00',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  strokePosition: 'CENTER', // causes errors even in chrome
  fillColor: '#00FF00',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  center: {lat: -33, lng: 151};
});
```

I have never seen strokePosition work in all the years I've used the API through many versions, despite it being in the documentation since forever:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolygonOptions.strokePosition

Note that it doesn't matter that my code shows a circle - the documentation states that strokePosition works on most shapes (and definitely for polygons and circles). Either way, I've tried it on Circles, Polygons and Rectangles and none of them work.

Here is a fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/1f4rche6/

Google search doesn't seem to produce any results of people who can't get it to work, although I find this very hard to believe. I also can't find a working example or fiddle anywhere online.

Has anyone actually been able to make strokePosition lie INSIDE or OUTSIDE their polygons? If so, what particular brand of magic did you weave to get it to work?

EDIT: It seems this is a bug with the API. I've added it to the bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177597389

Comment: It doesn't work. I can confirm that. Setting the `strokePosition` to `OUTSIDE` or `INSIDE` produces an error: `poly.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: h[v] is not a function`. It looks like a bug and I found nothing about it. You should open a new bug in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) with a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue (JSFiddle for example).

Comment: Here is one: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/98vL2zp5/

Comment: @MrUpsidown I think I beat you to it :) Updated my question. I'll also add it to the bug tracker. Very strange that it's never been noticed before.

Comment: Sure, anything goes... the error is the same in your fiddle so that's fine!

Comment: @MrUpsidown Cheers - I've added it to the bug tracker as you suggested.

Comment: You should link this question in the bug tracker, and a link to your bug in this question for clarity.

Comment: It gives no error if the value is for example `google.maps.StrokePosition.CENTER` - according to the documentation, its type is `StrokePosition`.

Comment: @alpakyol It doesn't give an error when you set the key to StrokePosition because you have just added a new key called "StrokePosition" that doesn't do anything. It also doesn't work to set the stroke's position (obviously). It's like adding another key to the object called "justMakeThisWork" - it doesn't do anything except hold whatever value you've assigned to that key.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Great suggestion regarding cross-linking. I've done so.

Comment: @alpakyol is right... you must use `google.maps.StrokePosition.INSIDE` or `google.maps.StrokePosition.OUTSIDE` etc. and not just `INSIDE` as a string. They are constants. It could be clearer from the docs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment and sorry for not realizing that earlier, the constants for `strokePosition` must be used as `google.maps.StrokePosition.CENTER`, `google.maps.StrokePosition.INSIDE` and `google.maps.StrokePosition.OUTSIDE`.

It works as expected when used this way as you can see in the below example. Same rectangle, with the 3 different stroke positions:

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 9)
  };

  var map_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-1'), mapOptions);
  var map_2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-2'), mapOptions);
  var map_3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-3'), mapOptions);

  // Create a rectangle
  var rectangle_1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    strokeColor: 'yellow',
    strokePosition: google.maps.StrokePosition.CENTER,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(33, 3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(44, 25)),
    map: map_1,
    zIndex: 0
  });

  var rectangle_2 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    strokeColor: 'yellow',
    strokePosition: google.maps.StrokePosition.INSIDE,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(33, 3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(44, 25)),
    map: map_2,
    zIndex: 0
  });

  var rectangle_3 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    strokeColor: 'yellow',
    strokePosition: google.maps.StrokePosition.OUTSIDE,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(33, 3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(44, 25)),
    map: map_3,
    zIndex: 0
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas-1,
#map-canvas-2,
#map-canvas-3 {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas-1"></div>
<div id="map-canvas-2"></div>
<div id="map-canvas-3"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I never would have worked that out from the google maps API documentation which I think should be updated. Also, it's not intuitive to infer this behaviour from other polygon object key/value pairs which usually pass styling options as numbers or strings. Thanks so much for solving this for me - my app looks so much better now with this option. And apologies to @alpakyol who was on the right track with his comment. Please let me know what I should do with the ticket I lodged in the issues tracker.

Comment: I would just comment in the issue tracker that you found the solution and maybe add that the docs could be clearer on that subject...